# Tycho compiler plugin fail to generate lombok functions

Tags: eclipse-plugin, maven-3, lombok, tycho

We have an OSGI framework and we are introducing Lombok in it.
In the pom.xml we added the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.22</version>
</dependency>
```

but mvn install compilation still fail with

> org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-compiler-plugin:2.0.0:compile (default-compile) on project XXX: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
> [ERROR] ...
> [ERROR] ...
> [ERROR] The method `setXXX(String)` is undefined for the type XXX

From Eclipse, everything compile and is working fine.
`lombok.jar` was also added to `Bundle-ClassPath` of `MANIFEST.MF`
We added the `annotationProcessorPaths` to the `pom.xml` without success

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.22</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**EDIT**
Even when configuring tycho compiler it doesn't work

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho-version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${compileSource}</source>
                <target>${compileSource}</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <processor> lombok.launch.AnnotationProcessorHider$AnnotationProcessor
                    </processor>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

when I added `set MAVEN_OPTS="-javaagent:C:\\Eclipse\\lombok.jar"` compilation worked, so is there any way to add this argument inside the compiler configuration in the `pom.xml` with a generic path to the `lombok.jar`

Comment: I believe tycho uses [tycho-compiler-plugin](https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-compiler-plugin/plugin-info.html) rather than `maven-compiler-plugin`

Comment: Yes, the above is one of things we tested. even with this it does not work :       <plugin>
 <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
 <artifactId>tycho-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>${tycho-version}</version>
 <configuration>
  <source>${compileSource}</source>
  <target>${compileSource}</target>
         <compilerArguments>
   <processor>
    lombok.launch.AnnotationProcessorHider$AnnotationProcessor
   </processor>
  </compilerArguments>
 </configuration>
</plugin>

Comment: [edit] your question to add new information

Comment: Eclipse bug [502181](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=502181) appears to say tycho cannot be configured for this

Comment: Lombok rewires the compiler to do its magic, which is why these things happen.   If you just want the easy getter/setter generation, look into Records in Java 17 LTS which is part of the language so it is guaranteed to be well supported without the hoops that tycho-lombokizer has to jump through.

Answer (score 3):

I'm succeeded in using Lombok within a eclipse plugin, and building the plugin with tycho.
https://github.com/poul-m/tycho-lombokizer

Comment: Nice! Thanks for sharing your work. Please consider contributing this to the Eclipse Tycho project.

Answer (score 2):

> when I added set MAVEN_OPTS="-javaagent:C:\Eclipse\lombok.jar" compilation worked, so is there any way to add this argument inside the compiler configuration in the pom.xml with a generic path to the lombok.jar

I was able to create **.mvn/jvm.config** in my project directory and configure a path relative to the project directory in there. Maven Tycho then successfully build my project with Lombok annotations:

This would be the content of the jvm.config:

```
-javaagent:project/relative/path/to/lombok.jar
```

https://maven.apache.org/configure.html

Edit: I only tried it with Maven Tycho 2.7.0

Comment: Works also with Tycho 1.0.0